# Content of a table outside an outline

Tags: tables

I prepared a table and the \cmidrule line on the right side isn't as wide as the text in the right columnt ("Essential bits per lane").

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\ra{1.3}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{@{}lccp{1.2cm}p{0.8cm}cp{0.5cm}cp{1.4cm}p{1.4cm}}
\toprule

\textbf{Firmware}
& \textbf{Lanes}
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Used resources per design}}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Essential bits}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10}

& & LUT
& LUT per lane
& LUT RAM
& FF
& FF per lane
& BRAM
& Essential bits per design
& Essential bits per lane\\

\midrule
Content
& A
& B
& C
& D
& E
& F
& G
& H
& I\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Do you how any suggestion how can I lengthen that line?

[image: Picture of a table]

Thank you,
Krzysztof

Comment: You're using `\cmidrule(lr){9-10}`. The `lr` means the line should be shortened on the `l`eft and `r`ight for columns `9-10`. Drop the `r` to make it stretch to the end of the table.

Comment: Aside: Since you're resizing the tabular environment to occupy the width of the text block, the instruction `\centering` is redundant and should be omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Werner has already commented, if you don't want to trim the right-hand end of a `\cmidrule`, don't provide the `r` trimming directive.

That said, you shouldn't resort to using `\resizebox` to make the tabular material fit inside the text block. As the following solution shows, it's preferable to set the column widths more carefully (i.e., less wastefully...) and reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace. With these two methods exploited fully, it turns out that reducing the font size isn't even needed. The new code uses a `tabular*` environment instead of the `tabular` environment of your original code. A side benefit of using a `tabular*` environment is that you needn't provide trimming directives to `\cmidrule.

The following screenshot shows the tables that are produced by (a) the new solution and (b) your original code. I trust you agree that the font size reduction performed in (a) is far milder and hence more pleasant to the eye and the one in (b).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,graphicx,float,array}
\providecommand\ra[1]{\renewcommand\arraystretch{#1}} 

\newlength\mylena
\newlength\mylenb
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

Proposed new solution:
\begin{table}[h!]
\ra{1.3} 
%% \small no font size reduction is needed
\settowidth\mylena{LUT}
\settowidth\mylenb{Essential}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercolumn sep.
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lc *{5}{C{\mylena}}c *{2}{C{\mylenb}} }
\toprule
\textbf{Firmware} & \textbf{Lanes}
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Used resources per design}}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Essential bits}} \\
\cmidrule{3-8} \cmidrule{9-10}
& & LUT & LUT per lane & LUT RAM & FF & FF per lane & BRAM
& Essential bits per design & Essential bits per lane \\
\midrule
Content & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\bigskip
Original version:
\begin{table}[H]
\centering  % this is redundant
\ra{1.3}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lccp{1.2cm}p{0.8cm}cp{0.5cm}cp{1.4cm}p{1.4cm}}
    \toprule

    \textbf{Firmware}
    & \textbf{Lanes}
    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Used resources per design}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Essential bits}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10}
    & & LUT & LUT per lane & LUT RAM & FF & FF per lane & BRAM
    & Essential bits per design & Essential bits per lane \\
    \midrule
    Content & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```